# Is Python 3.4 backwards compatible for 2.7 programs/libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am deciding whether to install python 3.4 or 2.7 on my home server running Ubuntu Server 14.04.2. I want to ensure that it has support from all the most used python libraries (scipy, numpy, requests, etc) but I am not sure how many of these packages fully support 3.4.

Do all 2.7 packages work on 3.4? If no, what are the differences between the two that causes this errors?

Comment: No 3.4 is not backwards compatible with 2.7

Comment: for all 2.7 libraries/programs?

Comment: No, only packages specifically written to support both Python 2 and 3 will run on either.

Comment: what are the major differences between the two? which one is generally accepted to be the standard these days?

Comment: You need to look at release notes.  It's not appropriate to answer this comment on SO.

Comment: @user2237160: that's too broad and answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor versions of python are mostly backwards compatible, however major versions do not maintain backwards compatibility. There are many libraries that work with both, but the language itself does not make that guarantee.

Comment: this seems like a terrible decision by the Python group, how can any sort of legacy code exist and work if its not backwards compatible?

Comment: @user2237160: no, it is not terrible, it is pragmatic.  Languages like Python are in constant development and features become obsolete.  Those obsolete features can be a block to future development where they overlap.  Ruby has had a similar issue with v1.9.  If the developers don't take this brave step then the language becomes stagnant and obsolete.  Despite some noble efforts this has happened with Perl 5.  If Python did not move forward it would wither and die.

Comment: Backwards uncompatible changes are unfortunate, but necessary sometimes to improve and evolve the language. Consider that python only has two major versions (python1 was beta only if memory serves) since it's 2.0 release in 2000. Also, from a functional standpoint, it is incredibly easy for active projects to work with both 2 and 3. Python developers can't be asked to make every abandoned project work the same forever.

Comment: i suppose you're right, this gives some perspective.

Answer (score 4):

No, only packages specifically written to support both Python 2 and 3 will run on either.

It is possible to write *polyglot* Python, but this requires effort from the library author. Code written for Python 2.7 will not automatically work on Python 3.